# Scroll bar at the bottom on full page

Tags: css

I've hit a wall trying to figure out why my CSS is causing a scroll bar on a full page.

Here's my old div layout (no scrollbar issue):

```
Container 100% (width)
  wrapper 80%
    navMenu 100% 
    centerDoc 100%
```

I recently had to add another menu item (its a horizontal menu so new item added to to the right side). After adding the new menu item i found that when i resized the page(made it smaller) the new menu item would collapse to the left hand bottm corner (underneath the first menu item).

To fix this i changed my layout to the following:

```
 Container 100% (width)
   navMenu 100%      <-- moved navMenu out of wrapper
   wrapper 80%
     centerDoc 100%
```

This fixed the collpasing issue. But now there is a scroll bar at the bottom of page on a full page. and i can't seem to figure out how to get rid of it : /

HTML snippet:

```
<div id="conainer">
    <?php require_once 'includes/header.php';
          require_once 'includes/nav.php'; ?>

     <div id="wrapper">

     <p>this is the wrapper</p>

        <div id="centerDoc">
        <p>this is the centerDoc</p>    

    </div>  <!--centerDoc !-->
     </div> <!-- wrapper !-->           
       </div> <!--container !-->
```

NOTE: nav.php included the navMenu div

CSS snippet:

```
#container {
   margin:auto;
   width: 100%;  
}


 #wrapper{

    width:80%;
}

#navMenu{

    /*font-family: 'Tenor sans', Calibri, Times, Times, serif;*/
    margin-left:2px;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:15px;

    /*this keeps the drop down menu on top*/
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}


#centerDoc {

   margin-top:2.8%;
   margin-left:10px;
   float:left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I know this is a lengthy one but i'm just looking for some direction to fix the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` at the `container` class, that should hide the scroll.

It should be like this:

```
#container {
   margin:auto;
   width: 100%;  
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @greenhoodlum Could you provide a live example? in http://jsfiddle.net/ for example? Is that your full `css` snippet? (i don't see any scroll bar in the example you just updated)

Comment: you will notice that if you remove the navMenu div the scrollbar-like panel at the bottom disappears. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, you should answer your own question or close it.

Comment: Sorry, i meant, i notice the issue. I guess i meant to say the naMenu is casuing the problem but i'm unsure on how to resolve it.